# jQuery Mobile type page navigation in asp.net web forms?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, webforms

I have a asp.net web application and two web pages and a master page .
both the pages use the same master page .

I need to navigate from one one page to another without making the screen go blank or provide some kind of a transition effect like the one's that happen in **jquery mobile pages navigation** .

The web pages are being viewed on a mobile device ! Any suggestion as to how to implement this without using the jQuery mobile .

Or is there a separate plugin which handles just the page navigation providing a much better user experience.?

Answer (score 0):

No transition will not lead to better user experience, but this is beyond the point.

What you can do is add data-transition="none" to your links, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/VC7jY/

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" /> 
        <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>     
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>page1
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                Content1</div>
            <div  data-role="footer">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#page1" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" data-transition="none">One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#page2" data-transition="none">Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#page3" data-transition="none">Three</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="page2">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>page2
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                Content2</div>
            <div  data-role="footer">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#page1" data-transition="none">One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#page2" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" data-transition="none">Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#page3" data-transition="none">Three</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div data-role="page" id="page3">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>
                    page3
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                Content3</div>
            <div  data-role="footer">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#page1" data-transition="none">One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#page2" data-transition="none">Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#page3" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" data-transition="none">Three</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Of course this will not work if you are preventing AJAX page handling with **rel="external"** or **data-ajax="false"**. Or if you are using several large HTML files.